# VK API узнать id города запросом-строкой

Tags: vkontakte-api

есть запрос к VK API:

```
users.search(version=5.92,count=5,city=1)
```

запрос возвращает 5 пользователей из поиска по городу Москва (id=1)
В чем проблема: узнавать id города и потом вводить его в программу не удобно, гораздо проще ввести текст "Москва" например, и чтобы программа его конвертировала в  id, далее подставила в запрос. 
Есть ли запросы к VK API для конвертации строки-города в число-id? по документации ответа не нашел.
Если API такие запросы не поддерживает- как можно осуществить конвертацию без костылей и мата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[database.getCities](https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities) - Возвращает список городов.
[database.getCitiesById](https://vk.com/dev/database.getCitiesById) - Возвращает информацию о городах и регионах по их идентификаторам.